# Why a PhantomJS grid node is defined differently compared to other browsers

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, grid

I am trying to set up one of my Selenium Grid nodes using PhantomJS. (The rest of the nodes are all working fine with Firefox browsers)

Now generally, when we configure a node, we launch a `selenium-standalone-server-<VERSION>.jar` and apply a configuration we want for that specific node using a command line or using json configuration file. In case we want to use `FirefoxDriver`, we don't need to do anything else. If we want to use another browser, For example Chrome, we will just place a ChromeDriver executable on the node machine. So far so good.

Now when I am reading the instructions for PhantomJS configuration I see that:

1. I don't need to have a separate copy of GhostDriver (PhantomJS driver) as it is embedded into PhantomJS itself. That is fine.
2. I do have to register the node using phantomjs itself like that for example:

   `phantomjs --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444`

   rather than using the `selenium-standalone-server-<VERSION>.jar`, like for any other browser.

That's what seemed a bit unusual to me. Why is that different for PhantomJS? Does that mean that selenium server is somehow embedded into the phantomjs package as well?

I would expect to have same kind of configuration as with any other browser, meaning add a phantomjs as one of the available profiles into my `nodeConfig.json` file and have a phantomjs package sitting somewhere on the same node.

BTW, I still need to launch the `selenium-standalone-server-<VERSION>.jar` if I have other browser running on that node (which I do).